Numpy Std doesn't accept 'mean' as argument
I would like to calculate the mean and std for a list. Since the documentation (see here) states, that I could  give the mean as an argument to std to prevent its recalculation, I would like to use it and save some time when running the code.
But unfortunately  I get following error:
TypeError: nanstd() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mean'

I checked my version: 1.26.4, tried it with the nan-version of the functions and it never worked.
Furthermore I searched if this has been asked before, but without success.
Since I need to perform this calculation multiple times with longer arrays, everything to save some time is worth it for me.
This is my minimum working example:
import numpy as np 
print(np.__version__) 
x = [1,2,3,4,5, np.nan] 
print(x) 
mymean = np.nanmean(x) 
print(mymean) 
mystd = np.nanstd(a = x, mean = mymean)  
print(mystd)


Your version is 1.26, which doesn have a mean argument https://numpy.org/doc/1.26/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html

@TomMcLean Yes, but if you check the docs for 2.0 then it says new in 1.26.0 so it seems that somebody f'ed up.

Made a PR to fix that up in the docs. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/27839

@AKX Same is true for (regular) std() and var(), not only the nan versions. Compare for example the docs for 1.26 of var here without "mean" and the docs of 2.0 here stating "new in 1.26.0".

@simon Looks like that has been addressed in https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/27399 / https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/27443 :)

@AKX Oh great, thanks for pointing me there! :)

Updating to numpy 2.1.3 solved it.
Contrary to the documentation, which says it was added with 1.26.0, it is only available in a higher version.
Apparently there happened a mistake when creating the documentation. Thanks to @TomMcLean for pointing where to look at.
